# How to load images in a predefined order with HTML/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, css, dom

I Have 2 heavy images on my landing page as background. They are going to be displayed in a given order so I am trying to load them in that order for a better user experience. I tried the code below :

```
        function loadImages(){
            img1= new Image();
            img2= new Image();

            img1.onLoad=img1Loaded();
            img1.src='img/bg1.jpg';
        }

        function img1Loaded(){
            console.log('image1 loaded');
            window.document.getElementById('page1').style.background= " #009ee3 url(img/bg1.jpg) no-repeat left top"; 
            window.document.getElementById('page1').style.backgroundSize="cover";
            img2.onLoad=img2Loaded();
            img2.src='img/bg2.jpg';
        }
        function img2Loaded(){
            console.log('image2 loaded');
            window.document.getElementById('page2').style.background= ' #009ee3 url(img/bg2.jpg) no-repeat center top';
            window.document.getElementById('page2').style.backgroundSize="cover";

        }
```

The console messages :

```
image1 loaded
image2 loaded
```

appear in the right order but almost at the same time. After a few seconds, both images are displayed at the same time.

What's wrong with my solution and how should I do ?

Comment: You could expect that behavior if the images weren't being cached for some reason...

Comment: u need to call functions with settimeout to achieve ur task in javascript if u can use jquery ur task is done here..now u need to chose..http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/Svs7p/3/

Comment: Two very important things: 1) Javascript is case sensitive, and it's `onload` and not onLoad, 2) onload expects a function reference and not a call to a function (as long as this function doesn't return a function reference). The difference is the trailing parentheses `()` that you should omit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern web browsers rarely open only a single connection. After the HTML has downloaded, all resources will be collected and the browser will load many of them in parallel. This is why your approach probably doesn't help a lot.

The timing you see can have many reasons. The most common of them is that you have opened this page before and you still had the images in the cache. The browser will then emit a small HEAD request which allows it to determine whether the image in the cache is still "good enough".

Try again with your caches flushed.

**EDIT** As [devnull69](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030974/devnull69) said, you have two severe bugs in the code:

1. Setting `onLoad` has no effect; the event handler is called `onload`.
2. Instead of assigning a function reference, you actually call the function. Use `img1.onload=img1Loaded` instead.

Without these two bug fixes, the code above will:

1. Call `img1Loaded();` which prints `image1 loaded`
2. Call `img2Loaded();` which prints `image2 loaded`
3. Assign `img2.src` (loading the second image). This will actually trigger the loading after the script has returned.
4. Assign `img1.src` (loading the first image, probably in parallel with the other one)